# How to call an assembly code in c in an ARM code warriror project?

Tags: c, assembly, arm

I want to reset the PC pointer somewhere in my C code which probably requires some assembly functions.

So I followed the instructions on the arm website and then:

In one of .s files in my project, I added:

```
     PRESERVE8
     AREA    SCopy, CODE
     EXPORT reset 
   reset  
     LDR PC, #0                                             
     END
```

and then in one of my .c files, I did:

```
extern void reset();
```

and call the reset() function somewhere. However, I was always told the reset symbol can not be found. Did I miss something?

Comment: What assembler are you using?

Comment: Have you tried inline assembly instructions?

Comment: Try changing the name to `_reset` in your assembly code - GCC is probably prepending an underscore

Comment: `LDR PC, #0` isn't legal; I suspect you meant `LDR PC, =#0` (which would be effectively, `MOV PC, #0`)

Comment: @Doron  I am not sure... I am using Realview 3.0..

Comment: @FiddlingBits I tried but always could not get the right syntax... That's the reason why I ask this question here..

Comment: @Drew McGowen Tried.. Didn't help..

Comment: @scott But it didn't give me any assembly compilation error.

Answer (score 3):

**You can do it with pure C:**

```
typedef void(*func)();
func reset = NULL;
reset();
```

Comment: What an amazing coincidence! Just note, this only works for the example OP gave - it's not a general solution to calling ASM functions from C on ARM.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen: The reason for my question (which I'm still waiting for you to answer, BTW) is that I was intending to answer this question, and thought I'd try it first just to make sure it worked :) ... Now, as we both know - it does happen to work, and of course (as you mentioned), only for the purpose of setting the PC to 0 (hence my answer does not say anything about assembly).

Comment: Is `NULL` the address of `main`?  How does this work?  Is it safe?

Comment: @FiddlingBits: No, `NULL` is simply a pointer to memory address 0, and the code above does exactly what OP asks for - setting the program-counter to that memory address. If there's a valid opcode at that address (most likely because the program was built with its code-section starting at that address), then it is safe. Otherwise, the program will most likely crash. Since OP asks to do it, I suppose that the code-section of the program indeed starts at that address, and this operation is therefore safe. BTW, function `main` is not necessarily the entry-point of every program.

Comment: I'm most familiar with embedded microcontrollers.  For example, on the STM32, the first address is `0x08000000`.  In this case this function would most likely hard fault.

Comment: @FiddlingBits: Me too with STM32. But that's what OP is trying to do with `LDR PC, #0`, so who am I to argue with it? BTW, even on STM32, I believe that the `0x08000000` is configurable through the linker settings or through the linker command file (the one in your project ending with `.icf`).

Comment: @FiddlingBits: You're welcome, see you on an STM32 project one day :)

Comment: @barakmanos Hi, thanks for your answer. Your answer is neat. But what I really want to do is more than just resetting PC. So I really want a way to call assembly in c

Comment: @HaoShen: No problem, you are very much welcome. If this is what you really want, then I suggest that you publish it in another question.